# changing div when one next to it is hovered

Tags: html, css

I want to change the divs next to mine when they are hovered to make them smaller, allowing mine to get bigger. However when trying to use the + or ~ i cant seem to get it to work.

CSS

```
.MobileFM footerL img:hover + footerR{
    background:white;
}
.MobileFM footerL img:hover + footerM img{
    width: 30%;
}
.MobileFM footerL img:hover {
    width:34%;
}
```

html

```
<div class="MobileFM">
            <footerL>  <img ng-click="clickPic('help')" ng-src="pic/help.png"> 
             </footerL>
            <footerM> <img ng-click="clickPic('scan')" ng-src="pic/scan.png">
             </footerM>
            <footerR> <img ng-click="clickPic('feedback')" ng-src="pic/feedback.png"> </footerR>

    </div>
```

Comment: What kind of a tag is `footerL`? Also you pasted-in your CSS twice, no HTML made it. And last but not least, what is the CSS for the initial state of the elements?

Comment: Can you paste your html? It looks like your CSS got duplicated by accident. Also, can you clarify whether you want divs on both sides of the one you're hovering to change size, or only to one side?

Comment: both sides i apologize. The initial state of the elements is simply a width and background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of doing this with just CSS would be to wrap your elements in something (which you've already done), then use both the wrapper and the child elements for the hover effect. The basic idea is that when the wrapper element is hovered it makes all the children smaller but when one of the children is hovered, that particular child grows.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="background:red;">a</div>
    <div style="background:blue;">b</div>
    <div style="background:green;">c</div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width : auto;
    float : none;
}
div {
    width      : 33%;
    float      : left;
    height     : 25px;
    text-align : center;
}

#wrapper:hover div {
    width : 25%;
}

#wrapper div:hover {
    width : 50%;
}
```

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/F36W8/